# How to recursively find the latest modified file in a directory?

Tags: bash, filesystems, find

It seems that `ls` doesn't sort the files correctly when doing a recursive call:

```
ls -altR . | head -n 3
```

How can I find the most recently modified file in a directory (including subdirectories)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recursively find and list the latest modified files in a directory with subdirectories and times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566310/how-to-recursively-find-and-list-the-latest-modified-files-in-a-directory-with-s)

Answer (score 417, accepted):

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' \
| sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" "
```

For a huge tree, it might be hard for `sort` to keep everything in memory.

`%T@` gives you the modification time like a unix timestamp, `sort -n` sorts numerically, `tail -1` takes the last line (highest timestamp), `cut -f2 -d" "` cuts away the first field (the timestamp) from the output.

**Edit:** Just as `-printf` is probably GNU-only, ajreals usage of `stat -c` is too. Although it is possible to do the same on BSD, the options for formatting is different (`-f "%m %N"` it would seem)

And I missed the part of plural; if you want more then *the* latest file, just bump up the tail argument.

Comment: If order matters, you can switch use `sort -rn | head -3` instead of `sort -n | tail -3`. One version gives the files from oldest to newest, while the other goes from newest to oldest.

Comment: I had a huge directory (some ten thousands small files) and I was worried about the performance, but...this command run in less than one second! Great, many thanks!!! :-)

Comment: "For a huge tree, it might be hard for sort to keep everything in memory." `sort` will create temporary files (in `/tmp`) as needed, so I don't think that's a concern.

Comment: I've been doing almost exactly this for years.  It's a good example of a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Comment: modifying it to: `-printf '%T@ %Tb %Td  %TY %p\n'` will give you a date stamp (if needed) (similar to `ls`)

Comment: The %T@ find directive outputs seconds with fractions, and their sorting with -n appears to work by coincidence.  The sort manual has -g for "general numerical" values.  (I guess outputting stamps in a fixed width format with %T+ can sort lexicographically).

Comment: I find the following shorter and with more interpretable output: `find . -type f -printf '%TF %TT %p\n' | sort | tail -1`

Comment: If you know that files were last changed in the past i.e. week, the option `-mtime -7` could be added to `find` to greatly speed up the process.

Comment: Might be a shade faster to do sort -nr | head -1 to truncate the output of sort at the first line?

Comment: If you are going to print multiple and want a timestamp with sorts, change printf part to `%T@ %TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS %p\n`

Comment: @DewiMorgan Probably not much faster: sort has to see every line of input before it outputs anything.

Comment: @WayneConrad Yes, and I agree that `sort` is the majority of the time for any large dataset because it's roughly O(NlogN). But then for the next step, it only needs to pipe one line to `head` as O(1), instead of sending the entire output to be read by `tail`, as O(N). Because `sort` dominates the time taken, though, I agree it'd only make it "a shade faster" at best.

Comment: The accepted answer should be updated to use `du -s --time` as an alternative. This is much more memory friendly than using sort, particularly when dealing with millions of files. For example: `du -s --time --time-style='+%Y-%m-%d+%H:%M:%S.%N'`.

Comment: @ives Nice. It's unfortunate though that it only gives you the latest modified time, not the name of the newest file.  I guess you could probably rescan the folder for files modified at that time - or later - and the computational time, but it might have to re-thrash the disk.

Comment: For custom date formats while maintaining the proper sorting, I figured out that piping the result into `date` was possible like so: `find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d\" \" | date -r /dev/stdin '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

Comment: I find `%T+` instead of `%T@` to be more human-readable in case I want to look at the results (and not just the latest filename), such as `find . -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -nr | less`

Answer (score 146):

Following up on [@plundra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4561987/68063), here's the BSD and OS X version:

```
find . -type f -print0 \
| xargs -0 stat -f "%m %N" \
| sort -rn | head -1 | cut -f2- -d" "
```

Comment: Does the BSD / OS X `find` support `+` instead of `\;`? Because that does the same thing (passing multiple files as parameters), without the `-print0 | xargs -0` pipe.

Comment: What to do if I want to get last 5 or n number of files modified in descending order?

Comment: @khunshan change the `head -1` to `head -5`

Comment: Just because you started to care about newlines in filenames with `-print0` it won't prevent to break it when you sort it line by line.

Answer (score 23):

Instead of sorting the results and keeping only the last modified ones, you could use awk to print only the one with greatest modification time (in unix time):

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@\0%p\0" | awk '
    {
        if ($0>max) {
            max=$0; 
            getline mostrecent
        } else 
            getline
    } 
    END{print mostrecent}' RS='\0'
```

This should be a faster way to solve your problem if the number of files is big enough.

I have used the NUL character (i.e. '\0') because, theoretically, a filename may contain any character (including space and newline) but that.

If you don't have such pathological filenames in your system you can use the newline character as well:

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@\n%p\n" | awk '
    {
        if ($0>max) {
            max=$0; 
            getline mostrecent
        } else 
            getline
    } 
    END{print mostrecent}' RS='\n'
```

In addition, this works in mawk too.

Comment: This could be easily adapted to keep the three most recent.

Comment: This does not work with `mawk`, the Debian standard alternative.

Comment: No, but in that case you can use the newline character if it doesn't bother you ;)

Comment: I don't know if this is because I'm on OSX, but this has a _bunch_ of issues.
1. $0 is the entire line, not the first field (should be $1).
2. You shouldn't use getline because that will skip lines.
3. You need the -0 flag for find in your first command to use the '\0' delimeter.

Comment: @HarrisonMc I think it's supposed to skip lines - each result outputs two lines, and awk compares the first line and saves the second.  The less pathological case could be simplified to just output a single line and have awk spit out the "greatest" one.  `find . -type f -printf "%TF %TT\t%p\n" | awk '{if ($0>max) max = $0} END{print max}'`

Answer (score 17):

Shows the latest file with human readable timestamp:

```
find . -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM: %Tz %p\n'| sort -n | tail -n1
```

Result looks like this:

```
2015-10-06 11:30: +0200 ./foo/bar.txt
```

To show more files, replace `-n1` with a higher number

Answer (score 11):

This seems to work fine, even with subdirectories:

```
find . -type f | xargs ls -ltr | tail -n 1
```

In case of too many files, refine the find.

Comment: The `-l` option to `ls` seems unnecessary. Just `-tr` seems sufficient.

Comment: This seems to sort per directory, so it won't necessarily show the latest file

Comment: In case there are spaces in the file paths better do: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ltr | tail -n 1`

Comment: This does not find the latest files for me.

Comment: Think this breaks if there are spaces in filenames

Comment: The tail -n 1 isn't doing anything because what it's working on is one line anyway. And the -ltr  would do the same here as -l  because the ls is only seeing one file each time anyway. So this 'answer' is wrong on many levels.

Answer (score 10):

I had the trouble to find the last modified file under Solaris 10. There `find` does not have the `printf` option and `stat` is not available. I discovered the following solution which works well for me:

```
find . -type f | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs ls -E | awk '{ print $6," ",$7 }' | sort | tail -1
```

To show the filename as well use

```
find . -type f | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs ls -E | awk '{ print $6," ",$7," ",$9 }' | sort | tail -1
```

**Explanation**

- `find . -type f` finds and lists all files
- `sed 's/.*/"&"/'` wraps the pathname in quotes to handle whitespaces
- `xargs ls -E` sends the quoted path to `ls`, the `-E` option makes sure that a full timestamp (format *year-month-day hour-minute-seconds-nanoseconds*) is returned
- `awk '{ print $6," ",$7 }'` extracts only date and time
- `awk '{ print $6," ",$7," ",$9 }'` extracts date, time and filename
- `sort` returns the files sorted by date
- `tail -1` returns only the last modified file

Answer (score 7):

I use something similar all the time, as well as the top-k list of most recently modified files.  For large directory trees, it can be **much faster to avoid sorting**. In the case of just top-1 most recently modified file:

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | perl -ne '@a=split(/\s+/, $_, 2); ($t,$f)=@a if $a[0]>$t; print $f if eof()'
```

On a directory containing 1.7 million files, I get the most recent one in 3.4s, a speed-up of 7.5x against the 25.5s solution using sort.

Comment: Very cool: I just exchanged the last print with: system("ls -l $f") if eof() to see the date in an nice way, too.

Comment: @MartinT. : great, and you're welcome. It's strange to me that people have this instinct to sort things ( O(n log n) ) when an O(n) method is available. This seems to be the only answer avoiding sort. BTW, the goal of the command I suggested is just to find the path of the latest file. You could alias the command in your shell (e.g. as `lastfile`) and then you can do whatever you like with the result, such as `ls -l $(lastfile .)`, or `open $(lastfile .)` (on a Mac), etc.

Comment: Oh, I stand corrected: I see another answer below (@marco). +1.

Answer (score 6):

## Using `find` — with nice & fast time stamp

Here is how to find and list the latest modified files in a directory with subdirectories. **Hidden files are ignored on purpose.** The time format can be customised.

```
$ find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*' -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM %Ta %p\n' |sort -nr |head -n 10
```

### Result

Handles spaces in file names perfectly well — not that these should be used!

```
2017-01-25 18:23 Wed ./indenting/Shifting blocks visually.mht
2016-12-11 12:33 Sun ./tabs/Converting tabs to spaces.mht
2016-12-02 01:46 Fri ./advocacy/2016.Vim or Emacs - Which text editor do you prefer?.mht
2016-11-09 17:05 Wed ./Word count - Vim Tips Wiki.mht
```

### More

[More](https://hamwaves.com/find/en/index.html) `find` galore following the link.

Comment: What do you mean by "not that these should be used"?

Comment: @Michael On GNU/Linux and other Unix* systems, it is generally recommended not to use spaces in file names or directory names.

Comment: On mac I used the following replacement: `find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*' -exec stat -f '%Sm %N' -t '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %a' {} + | sort -nr | head -n 10`

Answer (score 5):

This gives a sorted list:

```
find . -type f -ls 2>/dev/null | sort -M -k8,10 | head -n5
```

Reverse the order by placing a '-r' in the sort command. If you only want filenames, insert "awk '{print $11}' |" before '| head'

Answer (score 4):

I find the following shorter and with more interpretable output:

```
find . -type f -printf '%TF %TT %p\n' | sort | tail -1
```

Given the fixed length of the standardised ISO format datetimes, lexicographical sorting is fine and we don't need the `-n` option on the sort.

If you want to remove the timestamps again, you can use:

```
find . -type f -printf '%TFT%TT %p\n' | sort | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d' '
```

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 13, the following does it, maybe a tad faster, as it reverses the sort and uses 'head' instead of 'tail', reducing the work.  To show the 11 newest files in a tree:

**find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n -r | head -11 |  cut -f2- -d" " | sed -e 's,^./,,' | xargs ls -U -l**

This gives a complete ls listing without re-sorting and omits the annoying './' that 'find' puts on every file name.

Or, as a bash function:

```
treecent () {
  local numl
  if [[ 0 -eq $# ]] ; then
    numl=11   # Or whatever default you want.
  else
    numl=$1
  fi
  find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n -r | head -${numl} |  cut -f2- -d" " | sed -e 's,^\./,,' | xargs ls -U -l
}
```

Still, most of the work was done by plundra's original solution.  Thanks plundra.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. I need to find the most recent file recursively. find took around 50 minutes to find.

Here is a little script to do it faster:

```
#!/bin/sh

CURRENT_DIR='.'

zob () {
    FILE=$(ls -Art1 ${CURRENT_DIR} | tail -n 1)
    if [ ! -f ${FILE} ]; then
        CURRENT_DIR="${CURRENT_DIR}/${FILE}"
        zob
    fi
    echo $FILE
    exit
}
zob
```

It's a recursive function who get the most recent modified item of a directory. If this item is a directory, the function is called recursively and search into this directory, etc.

Comment: This doesn't really work. You could have an old directory that contains the newest file

Answer (score 3):

To search for files in /target_directory and all its sub-directories, that have been modified in the last 60 minutes:

```
$ find /target_directory -type f -mmin -60
```

To find the most recently modified files, sorted in the reverse order of update time (i.e., the most recently updated files first):

```
$ find /etc -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort -r
```

Answer (score 1):

If running `stat` on each file individually is to slow you can use `xargs` to speed things up a bit:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%m %N" | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" "
```

Answer (score 1):

This recursively changes the modification time of all directories in the current directory to the newest file in each directory:

```
for dir in */; do find $dir -type f -printf '%T@ "%p"\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" " | xargs -I {} touch -r {} $dir; done
```

Comment: It breaks badly if any dirs contain spaces - need to set IFS and use quotes: 
    IFS=$'\n';for dir in $(find ./ -type d ); do echo "$dir"; find "$dir" -type f -printf '%T@ "%p"\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" " | xargs -I {} touch -r {} "$dir"; done;

Answer (score 1):

This simple cli will also work:

```
ls -1t | head -1
```

You may change the -1 to the number of files you want to list

Comment: No, it won't, as it is not recursive.

Answer (score 1):

The following command worked on Solaris :

```
find . -name "*zip" -type f | xargs ls -ltr | tail -1
```

Answer (score 1):

After using a `find`-based solution for years, I found myself wanting the ability to exclude directories like `.git`.

I switched to this `rsync`-based solution. Put this in `~/bin/findlatest`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Finds most recently modified files.
rsync -rL --list-only "$@" | grep -v '^d' | sort -k3,4r | head -5
```

Now `findlatest .` will list the 5 most recently modified files, and `findlatest --exclude .git .` will list the 5 excluding ones in `.git`.

This works by taking advantage of some little-used rsync functionality: *"if a single source arg is specified [to rsync] without a destination, the files are listed in an output format similar to ls -l"* (`rsync` man page).

The ability to take rsync args is useful in conjunction with rsync-based backup tools. For instance I use `rsnapshot`, and I back up an application directory with `rsnapshot.conf` line:

```
backup  /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/current/   home    +rsync_long_args=--archive --filter="merge /opt/atlassian/jira/current/backups/rsync-excludes"
```

where `rsync-excludes` lists directories I don't want to backup:

```
- log/
- logs/
- analytics-logs/
- tmp/
- monitor/*.rrd4j
```

I can see now the latest files that will be backed up with:

```
findlatest /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/current/ --filter="merge /opt/atlassian/jira/current/backups/rsync-excludes"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the command above useful, but for my case I needed to see the date and time of the file as well I had an issue with several files that have spaces in the names.
Here is my working solution.

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" " | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs ls -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this one, it is shorter:

```
find . -type f -print0|xargs -0 ls -drt|tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a pypi/github package for this question because I needed a solution as well.

https://github.com/bucknerns/logtail

Install:

```
pip install logtail
```

Usage: tails changed files

```
logtail <log dir> [<glob match: default=*.log>]
```

Usage2: Opens latest changed file in editor

```
editlatest <log dir> [<glob match: default=*.log>]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Fast, unlimited files supported, and special-characters safe:

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' \
| sort -zn | tail -zn1 | cut -zc 23- | xargs --null ls -l
```

Replace the final `ls -l` with whatever should process the filename.