# Find the files that have been changed in last 24 hours

Tags: linux, bash, find

E.g., a MySQL server is running on my Ubuntu machine. Some data has been changed during the last 24 hours.

What (Linux) scripts can find the files that have been changed during the last 24 hours?

Please list the file names, file sizes, and modified time.

Comment: You could use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561895/how-to-recursively-find-the-latest-modified-file-in-a-directory

Answer (score 627, accepted):

To find all files modified in the last 24 hours (last full day) in a particular specific directory and its sub-directories:

```
find /directory_path -mtime -1 -ls
```

Should be to your liking

The `-` before `1` is important - it means anything changed one day or less ago.
A `+` before `1` would instead mean anything changed at least one day ago, while having nothing before the `1` would have meant it was changed exacted one day ago, no more, no less.

Comment: nice! how about last 2 hours?

Comment: use "-mmin -120" instead of mtime

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I want to get the return value, if this command got some modified file and if not ?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you want to check a directory if any files within were modified and return a boolean value telling you if there are any?

Comment: why the `-` before the numeric value?

Comment: The argument to -mtime is interpreted as the number of whole days in the age of the file. -mtime +n means strictly greater than, -mtime -n means strictly less than.

Comment: To the reader: don't forget to remove the `-ls` when using in a script

Answer (score 74):

Another, more *humanist* way, is to use the `-newermt` option which understands human-readable time units (see `man find` and search for `-newerXY`).

Unlike the `-mtime` option which requires the user to read the `find` documentation to figure out what time units `-mtime` expects and then having the user convert its time units into those, which is error-prone and plain user-unfriendly. `-mtime` was barely acceptable in the 1980s, but in the 21st century `-mtime` has the convenience and safety of stone age tools.

Example uses of `-newermt` option with the same duration expressed in different human-friendly units:

```
find <directory> -newermt "-24 hours" -ls
find <directory> -newermt "1 day ago" -ls
find <directory> -newermt "yesterday" -ls
```

Comment: "(see man find and search for -newerXY)"   and then "Unlike -mtime option which requires the user to read find documentation" 

Answer (score 51):

You can do that with

```
find . -mtime 0
```

From `man find`:

> [The] time since each file was last modified is divided by 24 hours and any remainder is discarded.  That means that to
>          match -mtime 0, a file will have to have a modification in the past which is less than 24 hours ago.

Answer (score 15):

On GNU-compatible systems (i.e. Linux):

```
find . -mtime 0 -printf '%T+\t%s\t%p\n' 2>/dev/null | sort -r | more
```

This will list files and directories that have been modified in the last 24 hours (`-mtime 0`). It will list them with the last modified time in a format that is both sortable and human-readable (`%T+`), followed by the file size (`%s`), followed by the full filename (`%p`), each separated by tabs (`\t`).

`2>/dev/null` throws away any stderr output, so that error messages don't muddy the waters; `sort -r` sorts the results by most recently modified first; and `| more` lists one page of results at a time.

Comment: You could also use `| less` instead of `| more`, I suppose.

Comment: `more` or `less`... ;)

Answer (score 9):

For others who land here in the future (including myself), add a -name option to find specific file types, for instance: `find /var -name "*.php" -mtime -1 -ls`

Answer (score 5):

This command worked for me

```
find . -mtime -1 -print
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the files...

You can set type f = file

```
find /directory_path -type f -mtime -1 -exec ls -lh {} \;
```