# find files which have been modified in the last 30 minutes in Linux

Tags: linux, setuid

how to find files based upon time information, such as creation, modified and accessed. It is useful to find files before a certain time, after a certain time and between two times. what command in Linux would i have to use ?

I understand to find setuid files on linux computers i would have to use :

> find / -xdev ( -perm -4000 ) -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l

How do i check for files which have been modified in the last 30 minutes. (I created a new file called FILE2)

Comment: Take a look to find manual ;)

Comment: Offtopic for SO. Belongs on superuser.com, perhaps

Comment: BTW, your command can be more easily written as `find / -xdev ( -perm -4000 ) -type f -ls`. I think you can also drop the parentheses and `-xdev` might be unnecessary as well, depending on where you really wanna search. Again, refer to the man and make the choice yourself.

Comment: Check this and the manual http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085958/scripts-find-the-files-have-been-changed-in-last-24-hours

Answer (score 1):

Just add `-mtime -30m`. I might be wrong about the actual syntax, but you get the idea. See `man find`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer on your question is

```
find . -cmin -30 -exec ls -l {} \;
```