# How to Grep from files created in last 24 hours

Tags: shell, unix, grep

Files are created at regular interval with the name which do not contain any timestamp.

How can I `grep`/filter any text from these files created in last 24 hours or with creation date of the files?

```
/data/logs/file*.log
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `find` to get the files in `/data/logs/` on the form `file*log` that were modified on the last 24 hours:

```
find /data/logs/ -mtime -1 -name file*log
```

Then, just `grep` through `exec`:

```
find /data/logs  -mtime -1 -name file*log -exec grep "whatever" {} \;
```

If you also want to show the filename, use `-H` [as suggested by Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898469/how-to-grep-from-files-created-in-last-24-hours/27898525?noredirect=1#comment44197840_27898525) --> `... -exec grep -H "whatever" {} \;`.

Credits to [Scripts: find the files have been changed in last 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086041/1983854).

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that `grep -H` might make it easier to see the filenames as well.

Comment: @MarkSetchell true and helpful. I just updated the answer with your suggestion. Thanks!