# Copy specific named directories which content changed the last 24 hours

Tags: linux, unix, find, rsync, cp

i can recursivly find and copy all my test-directories (with content) of the current directory:

```
find . -name test ! -path "./my_dest/*" -exec cp -r --parents {} /path/to/my_dest  \;
```

But now I want to copy only that test-directories (with content), which content was changed within the last 24 houres.

What do I have to add to my line above?

Edit: I want to have the same results as my find-line above, but I want only that entries in my result, in which folders a folder or a file has been changed within the last 24hours (or something else).

The line

```
find . -name test ! -path "./my_dest/*" ! -ctime +0 -exec cp -r --parents {} /path/to/my_dest  \;
```

does not do that! This line would find&copy only the folderchanged test-folders but not the filechanged test-folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the files that have been changed in last 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085958/find-the-files-that-have-been-changed-in-last-24-hours)

Comment: @oguzismail: NO, it isnt a duplikate of that post!! Where is our conversation gone??!!  Btw: If I add a new folder to one of my test-folders, than your code was working fine... but I didn't want to get the folders with changed folders, but I want to get the folders with changed files also...

Comment: btw: That possible duplikate is some months ago and it is a completly other problem...(and none of the difficult ones ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You use the `rsync` command built specifically for this task. Here is the [documentation](https://www.lifewire.com/copying-directories-with-rsync-3971105) and the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).