# PHP Include $newest Issue

Tags: php, blogs

I'm trying to create a very simple php blog, have got as far as including files in a directory and only including the newest file in index.php.

I would like for only a certain section of the newest file to display, can this be done?

Current code used on index.php is below.

```
<?php 
$files = glob('blog/*.php'); 
sort($files);      
$newest = array_pop($files); 
include $newest;
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any error ? Does the variable $newest contain anything ? Have you tried to echo it ?ň

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the newest file by modification time, you need to access `mtime` field of data, which will be provided by [stat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) function:

```
$rgFiles = glob('blog/*.php');
usort($rgFiles, function($sFileOne, $sFileTwo)
{
   $rgStatOne = stat($sFileOne);
   $rgStatTwo = stat($sFileTwo);
   return $rgStatOne['mtime']<$rgStatTwo['mtime']?-1:$rgStatOne['mtime']!=$rgStatTwo['mtime'];
});
$sFile = array_pop($rgFiles);
```

However, you can achieve that via shell-call and command like:

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" "
```

combined with [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or similar (full variant see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561895/how-to-recursively-find-the-latest-modified-file-in-a-directory))

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

When you include a file, it is just like taking that files contents and adding to your script at that location.  You need to have logic in your included file to determine what to display.  The `include` statement along will not do what you want.