# How to find the latest executable file in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm on linux an I want to know how to find the latest executable file in a directory?
I already know how to find the latest with:

```
ls -rt1 | tail -1
```

but how to filter out executable files?

---

EDIT:
I found a solution:

```
find path/to/dir/myfile* -perm /u=x,g=x,o=x -mtime 0 | tail -1
```

is this save? or is there a better solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the basic `find` command to look for files starting on current directory:

```
find . -type f
```

Let's add functionalities:

- To find executables you can use the `-executable` option:

  ```
  find . -type f -executable
  ```
- To just find on one level of depth, that is, not within subdirectories, use the `-maxdepth 1` option:

  ```
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
  ```
- To find last modified file in a directory, you can use [How to recursively find the latest modified file in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561895/how-to-recursively-find-the-latest-modified-file-in-a-directory):

  ```
  find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" "
  ```

All together, this looks for last modified executable file in one level depth:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" "
```

Comment: Ok but i want to get the **latest** executable of a specific directory not all the executables. i found a solution i added to my post look at the edit note. I want to ask if this is save or is there a better solution

Comment: Did you read the full answer? Last command returns a single file, you just have to replace `find .` for `find /your/dir`.