# How to recursively find the latest date and time of file modification in directory?

Tags: bash, filesystems

I am aware of [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561895/how-to-recursively-find-the-latest-modified-file-in-a-directory).

What I want is **just** the date and time of the last modification for any file inside a directory (recursively, the whole tree). Is there any **fast** way to do this for large directories?

Alternatively, I could also use a check telling me whether there was any modification after a given date.

Comment: so basicaly, you want a list of timestamp for last modification? do you want a specific format ? When you said `I could also use a check telling me whether there was any modification after a given date` is this your final goal or something you could work from ?

Comment: If you want *just* the date and time, can you not modify the command in the linked question not to output the filename?

Comment: @Aserre it might be an option, just getting the date would be preferable

Comment: @arco444 Sure, but I thought there might be a way to get just the date, but faster.

Answer (score 1):

To list the timestamp of all files in the folder :

```
 find . -type f -printf '%t\n'
```

To get a unix timestamp :

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@\n'
```

To list the timestamp of all files that were modified within the last 5 days

```
find . -type f -mtime -5 -printf '%t\n'
```

Note : all those commands are recursives