# Rename the most recent file in each group

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i try to create a script that should detect the latest file of each group, and add prefix to its original name.

```
ll $DIR
asset_10.0.0.1_2017.11.19 #latest
asset_10.0.0.1_2017.10.28
asset_10.0.0.2_2017.10.02 #latest
asset_10.0.0.2_2017.08.15
asset_10.1.0.1_2017.11.10 #latest
...
```

2 questions:

1) how to find the latest file of each group?

2) how to rename adding only a prefix

I tried the following procedure, but it looks for the latest file in the entire directory, and doesn't keep the original name to add a prefix to it:

```
find $DIR -type f ! -name 'asset*' -print | sort -n | tail -n 1 | xargs -I '{}' cp -p '{}' $DIR...
```

What would be the best approach to achieve this? (keeping xargs if possible)

Comment: [How to recursively find the latest modified file in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4561895/3776858)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Selecting the latest entry in each group

You can use `sort` to select only the latest entry in each group:

```
find . -print0 | sort -r -z | sort -t_ -k2,2 -u -z | xargs ...
```

First, sort all files in reversed lexicographical order (so that the *latest entry* appears *first for each group*). Then, by sorting on group name only (that's second field `-k2,2` when split on underscores via `-t_`) and printing unique groups we get only the first entry per each group, which is also the latest.

Note that this works because `sort` uses a **stable sorting** algorithm - meaning the order or already sorted items will not be altered by sorting them again. Also note we can't use `uniq` here because we can't specify a custom field delimiter for `uniq` (it's always whitespace).

#### Copying with prefix

To add prefix to each filename found, we need to split each **path** `find` produces to a directory and a filename (basename), because we need to add `prefix` to filename only. The `xargs` part above could look like:

```
... | xargs -0 -I '{}' sh -c 'd="${1%/*}"; f="${1##*/}"; cp -p "$d/$f" "$d/prefix_$f"' _ '{}'
```

Path splitting is done with [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), namely prefix (`${1##*/}`) and suffix (`${1%/*}`) [substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal).

---

Note the use of `NUL`-terminated output (paths) in `find` (`-print0` instead of `-print`), and the accompanying use of `-z` in `sort` and `-0` in `xargs`. That way the complete pipeline will properly handle filenames (paths) with "special" characters like newlines and similar.

Comment: Pretty cool! (But it looks like OP will need a bit more help with adding the prefix correctly.)

Comment: Thanks, will add that too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! taking this approach :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in bash alone, rather than using external tools like `find` and `sort`, you'll need to parse the "fields" in each filename.

Something like this might work:

```
declare -A o=()                         # declare an associative array (req bash 4)

for f in asset_*; do                    # step through the list of files,
  IFS=_ read -a a <<<"$f"               # assign filename elements to an array
  b="${a[0]}_${a[1]}"                   # define a "base" of the first two elements
  if [[ "${a[2]}" > "${o[$b]}" ]]; then # compare the date with the last value
    o[$b]="${a[2]}"                     # for this base and reassign if needed
  fi
done

for i in "${!o[@]}"; do                 # now that we're done, step through results
  printf "%s_%s\n" "$i" "${o[$i]}"      # and print them.
done
```

This doesn't exactly *sort*, it just goes through the list of files and grabs the highest sorting value for each filename base.

Comment: magnificent! too heavy for this task, but you definitely saved me a future question, as this is smth i was trying to "cook up" for another task. thanks again