# How to recursively find the latest modified file in a directory (in Solaris)?

Tags: unix, recursion, find, solaris, sunos

There's already [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561895/how-to-recursively-find-the-latest-modified-file-in-a-directory) about this that has the following answer:

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" "
```

But I get the following error when I run this on Solaris

```
find: bad option -printf
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
```

And here's what I get when I run `uname -a`

```
SunOS <SERVER NAME HERE> 5.10 Generic_150400-59 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise
```

Does anyone know the Solaris Equivalent? Please and Thank You!

Please and Thank You!

Comment: What's wrong this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18641147/4756299) on the question you linked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recursively find the latest modified file in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561895/how-to-recursively-find-the-latest-modified-file-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

"find" in Solaris doesn't have "-printf" option.

But you can do the following.

```
find . -type f -exec /bin/ls -E {} \; | sort -k6,7 | tail -1
```

Then, you can see somthing like this.

```
rw-r--r--   1 root     other          109 2018-09-13 00:37:39.295187000 +0900 ./newest.txt
```