# Looping ls -ltrh | tail -3 and cat the result and pass it to csv file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to list last 3 modified  files in /user directory , and then cat the result for every file , after the cat would like to awk and print 2 column and pass all the out put to csv file .

`for i in $(ls); do cat "$i"; done;`

Here will list and cat all the files, but i do not know how to cat just last 3 files

Any idea

Desired result :
csv-file

file-name , 1st clom , 3 colm

`for i in $(ls); do cat "$i"; done;`

Here just cat all the files :(

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: [BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003): *How can I sort or compare files based on some metadata attribute (newest / oldest modification time, size, etc)?*

Comment: please update the question with 3 sample input files, the `awk` code you've attempted, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected contents of the csv file

Comment: This might help: [How to recursively find the latest modified file in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4561895/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

3 most recent files:

```bash
stat -c '%Y:%F:%n' * | grep ':regular file:' | sort -t: -n | cut -d: -f3- | tail -3
```

And then cat them:

```bash
... | xargs cat
```

Comment: Going to misbehave with filenames with spaces, backslashes, quotes or newlines in their names.